# compare two column in a file using awk

Tags: shell, awk, scripting

For example, I have the data as below in file

```
IP=0.0.0.0 FIRST=20140626 LAST=20140626

IP=1.1.1.1 FIRST=20140626 LAST=20140626

IP=2.2.2.2 FIRST=20140626 LAST=20140626

IP=3.3.3.3 FIRST=20140626 LAST=20140626

IP=4.4.4.4 FIRST=20140626 LAST=20140626
```

I need to compare whether the FIRST and LAST coulmn are same for each IP
I am trying to use awk to search the FIRST and LAST pattern

Any help much appreciated

Comment: did you want to print the lines which has same ip's in first and last?

Comment: @AvinashRaj The proper question is "What have you tried?"

Comment: `awk -F "=" '$4 == $6{print $2": is same"}'`

Comment: didnt try it, whats up with it ?

Comment: i searched the pattern using awk and have cut to get the first and last column l i need to compare them now for each IP

Comment: @user3779820 Edit your question and show us what you've tried.

Comment: @Jidder I didn't try it either, but think about it, there will only be 4 fields in total if you split on the `=`. You mean to split on ` |=` (space and `=`).

Comment: File as above in my intial comment; I need to now compare the FIRST and LAST value for each IP
and echo EQUAL if passed or FALSE if failed

$ FIRST=`awk '{print $2}'  /tmp/aa.txt  | cut -c7-14`

$ LAST=`awk '{print $3}'  /tmp/aa.txt  | cut -c7-14`

$ echo $FIRST
20140626 20140626 20140626 20140626 20140626

$ echo $LAST
2040626 0140626 0140626 0140626 0140626

Comment: @ooga isnt that `or` though not `and` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this awk command to print `Equal` or Not equal according to the ip's present in the first and last.

```
$ awk -F[\ \=] '!NF{next} { if($4==$6) {print "Equal"} else print "Not Equal"}' file
Equal
Equal
Equal
Equal
Equal
```

Comment: Thanks I need only one output, i.e EQUAL or UNEQUAL

Comment: Why downvoters fail to revert back their vote after the update? or why they fail to provide a reason?

Comment: thanks I am trying like this any idea how can I update my syntax?                       $ for K in `cat /tmp/server-list`;do FIRST=`grep $K /tmp/aa.txt | awk '{print $2}'  /tmp/aa.txt  | cut -c7-14` && LAST=`grep $K /tmp/prav.txt | awk '{print $2}'  /tmp/aa.txt  | cut -c7-14` ; if [ $LAST -eq $FULL ]; then echo "EQUAL"; else echo "UNEQUAL"; fi ;done
-bash: [: too many arguments
UNEQUAL
-bash: [: too many arguments
UNEQUAL
-bash: [: too many arguments
UNEQUAL
-bash: [: too many arguments
UNEQUAL
-bash: [: too many arguments
UNEQUAL
-bash: [: too many arguments
UNEQUAL

Comment: @user3779820 ask it as another question. Because editing your question is not a good idea.

Comment: @zx81 you're looking at the wrong place, what you're seeing is that I've been downvoted too. I never downvoted a single answer nor question, you can see that at botton of the screen http://stackoverflow.com/users/3640161/tiago, I have 17 votes cast all of them are up votes. 12 for answers 5 for questions. But I do appreciate the downvote when they are commented and udone after the edit.

Comment: @Tiago You're entirely right. I completely misunderstood the data. Sorry about the misleading and confused comment.

Answer (score 0):

don't know your exact output format, this may help:

```
awk -F'[= ]*' 'NF{print $2, ($4!=$6?"not ":"")"same"}' file
```

with your example, it prints:

```
0.0.0.0 same
1.1.1.1 same
2.2.2.2 same
3.3.3.3 same
4.4.4.4 same
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do:

```
awk -F ' |=' '$4==$6'
```

That's a bit Idiomatic, it will only print if `$4=$6`

Comment: I don't downvote any answers, but I guess your cmd doesn't output the "not equal" lines?

Comment: @kent I think the requirement were very vague, nevertheless my answer is very effective, let's see if the downvoter will explain. cheers

Comment: @kent I didn't think you downvoted, BTW I learn a lot with your answers :)

Comment: From some time ,I don't downvote any answers @SO, not only for this question. since I think the people who posted answers were trying helping people. the answer may not good enough, but doesn't deserve downvoted. well it might violate the rule of SO, but ... my personal opinion..

Answer (score 0):

```
awk    '{split($1,i,"=");split($2,a,"=");split($3,b,"="); 
        if(a[2] == b[2]) print  i[2] " equal"; else print i[2]" not equal"; }' 
        input.txt
```

Output:

```
   0.0.0.0 equal
   1.1.1.1 equal
   2.2.2.2 equal
   3.3.3.3 equal
   4.4.4.4 equal
```

Where input.txt contains the required data